# equivalent of oracle profile in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

My Oracle database ha profile controlling the password and resources used for the users. I wonder how thats being taken care in postgresql. for example profile in oracle is -

```
CREATE PROFILE test_PROFILE
    LIMIT 
         COMPOSITE_LIMIT DEFAULT 
         SESSIONS_PER_USER DEFAULT 
         CPU_PER_SESSION DEFAULT 
         CPU_PER_CALL DEFAULT 
         LOGICAL_READS_PER_SESSION DEFAULT 
         LOGICAL_READS_PER_CALL DEFAULT 
         IDLE_TIME 10 
         CONNECT_TIME DEFAULT 
         PRIVATE_SGA DEFAULT 
         FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS UNLIMITED 
         PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME UNLIMITED 
         PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME DEFAULT 
         PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX DEFAULT 
         PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION DEFAULT 
         PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME DEFAULT 
         PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME DEFAULT 
         INACTIVE_ACCOUNT_TIME DEFAULT ;
```

Comment: There is no equivalent

Comment: So in postgresql, it manages the CPU by database engine itself? Also how does it control password retries and account locking?